# Раздача Wi-Fi при помощи /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: wifi, ubuntu

Добрый день! Network Manager снес сразу, как поставил Ubuntu. У меня ноутбук, вручную настроил интернет соединение:

Файл /etc/network/interfaces:    auto lo    iface lo inet loopback

```
auto eth0iface eth0 inet staticaddress 192.168.1.2netmask 255.255.255.0gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, настроить раздачу Wi-Fi таким же способом (ручной настройкой). желательно защитить Wi-Fi паролем и сделать автоматическую раздачу IP-адресов.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

**Вариант 1**

1. Вам надо настроить wifi-адаптер в режиме точки доступа. Это должно аппаратно поддерживаться чипсетом адаптера. Пишут что Atheros это может 100%. Как это сделать "ручной настройкой" описано [в этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/89420/).
2. Вам надо установить, настроить и запустить DHCP сервер для автоматической раздачи адресов подключившимся клиентом. Настройка DHCP сервера описана [в этой статье](http://howitmake.ru/blog/ubuntu/88.html), и [в этой](http://448dmg.ru/dhcp-server-nubuntu-278).
3. Если ваш ноутбук и будет шлюзом в интернет, то настройте на нём соответствующим образом файрвол и NAT. Описано [тут](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=107492.0), [тут](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Ubuntu_Internet_Gateway_Method_.28iptables.29) и ещё много где.
4. Ещё не помешает DNS-форвардер, фильтрация трафика и т.д.

**Вариант 2**

1. --- то-же ---
2. Вернуть Network Manager, поставить в нём пару галочек и не париться.

**Вариант 3**

1. Купить [роутер](http://market.yandex.ru/model.xml?modelid=4973968) за $25 и не париться.

Comment: Плюсую:1. Креативно2. Экономно3. Оптимально

Comment: Статья на хабре не помогает, уже делал по ней. хочется все же использовать 1 вариант, я с ним и просил помочь

Comment: Что именно не работает? Расскажите поэтапно, сообща что-то и получится.